# ECharts Xaxis name vertical position at top

Tags: javascript, echarts

my code in echarts is:

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    verticalAlign: 'left',
    axisLabel: {
      inside: true,
    },
    name: 'wow',
    nameLocation: 'start',
     nameGap: 5,
    nameTextStyle: {
      align: 'end',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom',
      fill: '#888',
      fontSize: 14,
      color: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'gray',
      padding: [8, 6, 4, 6],
      borderRadius: 6,
    },
   
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    position: 'right',
    
  },
  series: [
    {
      data: [150, 230, 224, 218, 135, 147, 260],
      type: 'line',
      
    }
  ]
};
```

I would like to have the Xaxis label name ('wow') to top of the graph, is it possible to have control on Y ? I tried padding, align and nameGap, no way. I can't use the name with the yAxis because I want the Y ticks show at right, and the name at left of the graph.

here the test:
[on echarts sandbox](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0A0J6AE2aMiAbVoBZGL1i0AKgFcqM2gHUqAlXIAWClQDEOEFQGVmphdFoBdPqVgA3Kh0hMANljcRW0Om6oAZmC8_LCMuHgAMowARlRuRKj26BDQeBACNGQcSnakAL556NCMALZZtADuwJUh9iXlkcBMkDB0eGCMLnX1ZVQA4owgRACsRbANVHJUGGAmFP6JoeiMXj50VNCa4-hOLhDunt6-sjHAYGDApT32ARBuCbIAxAAcbzekATBzEABeWQBGAAsO1g9GAbk4dEq2ggLA-6BijHoAGtWBxgJYBABhCFQ2ToxjcUEgRgCASpVhiF48WAANlpIPptmWsDOHEyHAASmSIApCPTxoV-CRhehyDh8Et7BRqHQHKslB8QMB0q0TrQjKxtMFxqK8nhnBAqALRKEkskhJ0xACRgAGWkAJgAzA7YI7HUzHQCabAAc6xn6gQB2J10u0s5JkSgVLzQZSg0L5EjWFD5ADcQA) [on codedandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-line-chart-forked-kywx93?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a second invisable xAxis and move it to the top:

```js
xAxis: [
    {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
        verticalAlign: 'left',
        axisLabel: {
            inside: true
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'category',
        name: 'wow',
        nameLocation: 'start',
        nameTextStyle: {
            align: 'end',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            fill: '#888',
            fontSize: 14,
            color: 'white',
            backgroundColor: 'gray',
            padding: [8, 6, 4, 6],
            borderRadius: 6
        },
        axisLine: { show: false }
    }
]
```

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXLANprrJnmxgCeIApkQOQDGAhmPQObABONTADSVyAEw5sixJgFkYQ2EwAqAV3oKmAdXqiNSgBYqNAMV4QNAZQ6WV0JgF1hVdADd6vSOwA2WLxC7QzF70AGZgQiLobLh4ADJsAEb0XkSozuQQ0HgQoozUvGqRsAC-IsVO5GnOtAzM7Jw8_BHp0GwAtnlMAO7AXc3OrR2xwPVQgYp4YGwe_VSD9Er0GGAWtMGpRVF-Acz00LoV6W4eEN6-_uNMCcBgYMBts84hEF4pigDEABzfj1QhMCsIAAvPIARgALIdnCxgF4-MwuvoIJxfuQEmwWABrLi8YC2UQAYVh8MUOLYAihVBAbFEokyXCkn0EsAAbMzIazHJtYNdeLleAAlGkQFSEVlFcpFaL4WKZPJIWB4fS9IghNhePD0EplMhc9A0HD4DZUGqdFzqtSPEDAbKQGDMMxcfThMiS9Casz0MWkKhVKjiKZSUEAVgADMyAEwAZnDsAjEY5EdBTNgoKjweZEIA7JGWaG9dU6J0_NB1Dr0PYUMUANxAA) is an example.